# Function reference and assert(0) in C++

Tags: c++, class, function, reference, struct

I wish to understand what `fetch().text` and `assert(0)` do below. I am not familiar with a function like `fetch()` that can refers to a member of the return type, i.e. `fetch().text`. Is this somehow enabled by the use of `assert(0)`?

```
class SimpleS{ 

  struct internal_element {
    const char *text;   
  };

 class SimpleE {
   public:

    SimpleE() {
    }

    const char* text() const {
      return fetch().text;  
    }

    void set_text(const char *text) {
      fetch().text = text;
    }

   private:

    internal_element& fetch() const {
      ... // some code
      assert(0);    
    }
}
```

Comment: The `... // some code` above `assert(0);` is important in explaining the code, there probably is some condition for the code `assert(0);` to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion has nothing to do with it. What's happening here is that fetch() returns a reference to an `internal_element`. That enables you to refer to members of that struct in the returned value:

```
fetch().text
```

refers to the `internal_element::text` member of the `internal_element` object returned by fetch().

As to why there's an `assert(0)` in there, no idea. You didn't give us the code. Usually, when a function ends with such an assert is because the programmer wants to catch cases where he didn't cover some possibility. For example:

```
if (condition)
    //...
else if (condition)
    //...
// We should have covered all possible conditions above and already
// returned. If we actually get here, then we did something wrong.
assert(0);
```

Answer (score 2):

The assert(0); will always fail. I suppose its purpose is to make sure that this method is never called in the first place.

(Assuming, of course, there is no condition for the assert(0); being run)

Answer (score 1):

```
return fetch().text
```

calls the function `fetch`. This presumably returns an object of class `internal_element`. It then accesses the `text` member of this returned object and returns it. It's effectively equivalen to:

```
internal_element temp = fetch();
return temp.text;
```

Answer (score 1):

If the `... // some code` in your code has a conditional return, `assert(0)` will never be called. `assert(0)` basically causes an exception and the program will die if the exception is not being caught in the calling function.

Answer (score 0):

In below code (which you shared), programmer got condition which make function return, thats what the // some code supposed to do...but if one of the the conditions is not true (and it return) control reaches end of function it means there is fatal error, so is the purpose of assert(0) at the end of function...

internal_element& fetch() const {

... // some code
      assert(0);
    }